# Video effects over the live webcam stream for a party

Tags: video, effects

The idea is to stream a webcam video from one party location to a projector in the main area. It would be cool if I can find a way to add "fun cat faces" effects or something similar on the fly to the video. There are plenty "face booth" phone apps for selfies, but I'm looking for using a stationary webcam connected to my computer and more faces at a time that on a usual phone. Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to need something out of your price range to complete such a task. Video, is far more complex to process in real time, than say a photo, that only analyzes a single frame and looks for simple objects like eyes, nose, mouthlines, as anchors.

The NewTek Tricaster ($20,000) line would be an option for this, but you'd need a company to come in to do it, and with a workflow pre-established to make this work.

In short. No, there is no easy way.